# Chrome Not Running With Specified Mobile Device (Mobile Emulation Mode)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

According to this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cxlWjscdiI the code below is supposed to enable that little mobile device icon when inspecting the code on page and show a grey circle cursor instead of an arrow when navigating page links. It is not doing that. I know that the device name I'm using is in the list of devices to emulate. Here is an image and code...
[image]

```
static IWebDriver driver = null;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.EnableMobileEmulation("iPhone 6/7/8");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login");
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this arguments `options.AddArguments("start-maximized");`